Lemma 2.4 of "On groups and fields definable in o-minimal structures"
I'm having some trouble understanding the proof of lemma 2.4 from the paper "On groups and fields definable in o-minimal structures" by A. Pillay.
Here we are working in an o-minimal structure $\mathcal M$ and $G$ is a definable group in $\cal M$.

I've been trying to understand this proof for the last couple hours, and so far, these are my main questions:

What does "$\mathcal M_0$ is a small model" mean? Why does it exist? (I'm guessing downward LK, but can anyone confirm this?)

What does $G^{M_0}$ mean? I'm guessing that it's the set of elements of $M_0$ that satisfy the formula used to define $G$, but isn't it possible that $G^{M_0} = \emptyset$?

Is the the existence of a generic $c \in G$ over $M_0$ such that $tp(c/M_0 \cup a)$ is finitely satisfiable in $M_0$ guaranteed to exist? Why is that?

What does $a_1\hat{} b_1$ and $a\hat{} b$ mean? I've never seen this notation and it isn't defined anywhere on the paper either.


I'm sorry for not showing my work, but my work so far has been trying to understand all the other parts of the proof that I didn't ask about, so there isn't any point in describing that here.
If you need me to carify any definitions that are not stated here let me know.

I made a slight edit to my answer, after rereading Pillay's definition of "generic point".

Thank you very much @AlexKruckman

(1) On p. 240, just before Section 1, Pillay writes "For convenience sake we will assume that $M$ is very saturated." What this means is that we assume $M$ is $\kappa$-saturated for some (big) cardinal $\kappa$, and having adopted this convention, "small" means "size less than $\kappa$".
As for existence of $M_0$, since $X$ is a definable set, there is a finite set $A$ of parameters used in the definition of $X$. By Löwenheim-Skolem, there is a small elementary substructure $A\subseteq M_0\preceq M$. In fact, we can take $|M_0| = |L|$.
(2) Yes, $G^{M_0}$ is the set of elements of $M_0$ satisfying the formula defining $G$. No, it cannot be empty: for any $M_0\preceq M$ and any formula $\varphi(x)$ (possibly allowing parameters from $M_0$), if $\varphi(M)$ is non-empty, then $M\models \exists x\, \varphi(x)$, so $M_0\models \exists x\,\varphi(x)$, and $\varphi(M_0)$ is non-empty.
That's a general fact. In our special case, $M\models \text{$G$ is a group}$, so $M_0\models \text{$G$ is a group}$, and groups are always non-empty. Stronger, it's a good exercise to show that $G^{M_0}\preceq G^M$.
(3) Let $c$ be a generic point of $G$ over $M_0$ (which exists directly from the definition of "generic point", Definition 1.3). Now let $p = \mathrm{tp}(c/M_0)$. Since this is a type over a model $M_0$, it is finitely satisfiable in $M_0$, so it extends$^{(*)}$ to a type $p'$ over $M_0\cup a$ which is finitely satisfiable in $M_0$. Let $c'\in M$ realize $p'$. (Incidentally, we use here the fact that $M_0$ is small and $M$ is sufficiently saturated to find this $c'$.)
$(*)$ The general fact used here is that if $p\in S(A)$ is a type which is finitely satisfiable in $A$ and $A\subseteq B$, then there is a type $q\in S(B)$ such that $p\subseteq q$ and $q$ is finitely satisfiable in $A$. If you don't know this, it's a good exercise to prove it.
(4) $a^\frown b$ just means the tuple obtained by concatenating the tuple $a$ with the tuple $b$. Often in model theory, we just write $ab$ for this. But since $a$ and $b$ are elements of a group, I suspect Pillay is being careful to write $a^\frown b$ so that $ab$ is not confused with $a\cdot b$ (the product of $a$ and $b$ in $G$).

I'm having some trouble understanding 3. Using (*), how can we guarantee that $c'$ is still a generic of $G$ over $M_0$?

@EduardoMagalhães $c$ and $c'$ have the same type over $M_0$, so they are both in $G$, and $\dim(c'/M_0)=\dim(c/M_0)=\dim(G)$. This shows that $c'$ is a generic point of $G$ over $M_0$. The fact that it is a generic point of $G$ over $M_0\cup a$ is explained in the proof.

Sorry to bother you again with this, but how does $X\cdot a^{-1}$ being large in $G$ imply that $c \in X \cdot a^{-1}$ by lemma 1.13? At least to me, this lemma looks completely unrelated to this

@EduardoMagalhães It should say Lemma 1.12.

is the fact $(*)$ true in general, or only when $M$ is sufficiently saturated?

@EduardoMagalhães The statement of Lemma 2.4 is true in any model (since dimension and largeness are preserved on passing up to a sufficiently saturated elementary extension, and the statement that finitely many translates of $X$ cover $G$ is definable, hence true back in the original model). And Lemma 2.4 easily implies $()$, since we can find finitely many elements of $M_0$ such that the translates of $X$ by these elements cover $G$. So yes, $()$ is true without any saturation assumptions on $M$.

But don't we need (*) in order to prove lemma 2.4 in the first place?

Yes: we prove $()$ for saturated models and conclude Lemma 2.4 for saturated models. Then (after the fact) we can see that Lemma 2.4 holds for all models, and thus $()$ also holds for all models.
